# How to stop Watchdog from logging "DEBUG" errors?

Tags: 7, log-messages

I get this error in my logs a lot:

```
Deprecated function: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; views_many_to_one_helper has a deprecated constructor in require_once() (line 127 of C:\...\sites\all\modules\contrib\ctools\ctools.module).
```

This is really not important to me and I don't want it filling up watchdog. Is there any easy way to tell Watchdog to not log these errors? Where can I change which errors get logged by watchdog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Drupal watchdog includes the errors raised by PHP, such as the one you mention.

It might be possible to use [hook_watchdog](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_watchdog/7.x) to filter out certain errors. However, it seems easier to change the PHP error level on your `settings.php` file, so that PHP does not complain about your ctools module.

- The list of possible PHP error levels is here: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php
- Some guidance about modifying the error levels on your `settings.php`file: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/show-all-errors-while-developing